# JQM Load Page in Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, autoload, jquery-mobile

I need to open my second page (id=objectside) in JQM Mobil after it's been alert in JavaScript:

```
      function showObjekt(val){
        $.getJSON('getObjectDetails.php?ido='+val, function(data) {
            //Overwrite divs in page objectside with values from json
              objectside.divid.innerHTML=data.value; //example how i overright it
        });
        $.mobile.changePage("#objectside");
  }
```

As you see i have modified serval divs in the page with the id objectside then I want to load this modified  page just like I Would be clickking on link with `href="#objectside"`.
This doesn't work. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the page via jQuery Mobile once you finish the JSON call:

```
$.getJSON('getObjectDetails.php?ido='+val, function(data) {

           $("#objectside").html(data.value);

           //Change page now
           $.mobile.changePage("#objectside");
        });
```

Comment: @LukasSchmidinger check my edit and check out that `data.value` contains the correct html...

Comment: THX a million times but perhabs u can help me with an other little mystery: i change the div linksdiv like this: var links='<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="links">';
                links+='<li><a data-theme="b" data-role="button" href="'+data.url.split("\\").join("")+'" target="_bank">Homepage</a></li>';
                links+="</ul>";
                 $("#linksdiv").html(links); The first Time I use the function it makes a button (as it should) the following times it just makes a ordinary link.

Comment: @LukasSchmidinger you are asking another question, but by far I can read you are not refreshing the listView, try  $('#mylist').listview('refresh');

Comment: @LukasSchmidinger please, accept the answer to close the question.